# How to connect jabber bot and php?

Tags: php, wordpress, xmpp

I want to use php for connecting to jabber bot.

Is there any solutions for using php to connect to jabber bot?

I am going to use WordPress as CMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the Wordpress.org Codex plugin listing, you will find there are many pre-made solutions to Jabber <--> WP integration:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/jabber/

Normally, I'd paste external link information right into the answer, though plugins come and go in popularity and maintenance, so best for future readers to go directly to the Codex, where the freshest and best plugins will be liste.